# Adding more pages or content in jQuery mobile panel

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I have below jQuery mobile panel basically this page for touchable desktop & tablet page. I want to added content in panel

**eg:**

1. when panel open it will show "A"
2. then I click on "A" it will redirect to "B" (which will be different page or whatever possible way) and show it content.

Markup and code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel"> 
    <h2>Panel Header</h2>
    <p>You can close the panel by clicking outside the panel, pressing the Esc key or by swiping.</p>
  </div> 

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Header</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the button below to open the Panel.</p>
    <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Page Footer</h1>
  </div> 
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

B page has list and four image:

```
<div>
<li>Name 1</li>
<li>Name 1</li>
<li>Name 2</li>
</ul
</div>

<div>
<img src="images/banner1.png">
<img src="images/banner1.png"> 
<img src="images/banner1.png"> 
<img src="images/banner1.png">  
</div>
```

I got from web, my panel is almost same. Now if from Panel menu I click "Money" new content must loaded in panel(I am not looking for accordion).

Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5xCg4/

Thanks in advance

Comment: paste your jQuery code.

Comment: Put a link to page B inside the panel???

Comment: @SalmanA: page B is different page, I want Page B must load in Panel only.

Comment: you cant load a page inside a panel. you can load contents of that page if that's what you want.

Comment: @Omar:Content will be also fine.

Comment: post sample of that page and its' content.

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Lcbd2/

Comment: @Omar: I was looking for the same. Thanks for your help!!!